# Overwriting custom string failing when non-default ctor was explicitly called

Tags: c++, string, cin, overwrite

For an exercise in Accelerated C++ I'm implementing a custom string class called `Str`. Everything worked fine when the underlying storage container was a custom vector (`Vec`) but now I've run into a weird situational problem I don't understand.

If I create a new `Str` object by explicitly calling the constructor like `Str newStr("some words");` and then try to overwrite it using `cin >> newStr;` the program crashes in the end, giving a SIGABRT in the debugger when it reaches the `Str` destructor (which is just `delete[] data;`).

This doesn't happen if I create a new, empty `Str` then use `cin` to fill it like `Str newStr; cin >> newStr;`, or if I use `cin` to overwrite a `Str` I made using `Str newStr = "some words";`, it only fails when I attempt to overwrite a `Str` made by explicitly calling a non-default constructor even though this type displays correctly before being overwritten.

Another weird thing in this case actually works fine if i just don't create any new `Str`s between creating/displaying the odd-behavior `Str` and using `cin` to change its value.

```
Str a = "Here is a";
Str b("And here is b");

cout << a << endl << b << endl;

Str c = "Finally we have c";
cout << c << endl;
cin >> c;
cout << c << endl << endl;

cin >> b;
cout << b << endl;
```

This shows you that you can overwrite `Str c` successfully, but crashes when you try to overwrite `Str b`. This, however, lets you overwrite `b` and the program completes successfully:

```
Str a = "Here is a";
Str b("And here is b");

cout << a << endl << b << endl;

cin >> b;
cout << b << endl;
```

`Str` contains private members `char* data`, `int length, limit` and the constructor being used for both `a` and `b` is:

```
Str::Str(const char* cp) {
    limit = length = std::strlen(cp);
    data = new char[length];
    for (size_type i = 0; i != length; ++i)
        data[i] = cp[i];
}
```

I also have `>>` friended and its implementation is:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Str& s) {
    delete[] s.data;
    s.length = s.limit = 0;

    char c;
    while (is.get(c) && isspace(c)) ;

    if (is) {
        do s.push_back(c);
        while (is.get(c) && !isspace(c));

        if (is)
            is.unget();
    }
    return is;
}
```

I know `push_back` might be an odd function to have in this class but it works fine even when using `cin` for a very long `Str` that takes many push_backs. I've tried tweaking different parts of the class/operators for hours and am stumped o_O

Lastly, I'm not sure why my copy ctor isn't being called (checked with `cout`s) during `Str` initialization that uses `Str newStr = "blah";` syntax, even though it works.

**Edit, push_back:**

```
void Str::push_back(char c) {
    if (length == limit) {
        limit = std::max(limit*2, 1);
        char* newData = new char[limit];

        for (size_type i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            newData[i] = data[i];

        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
    data[length++] = c;
}
```

Comment: When you used an underlying `std::vector` the `push_back()` function was built in.  Now you are using a buffer of chars you must have written your own `push_back()`.  It looks likely that this is where the error is.  Please post the source here.

Comment: When using a `Vec` I also had to write `push_back()` since that exercise involved making a custom class to act like a `std::vector`, edited to show my `Str::push_back()`, has seemed to work in other cases when it's called many times overwriting things like `Str someStr = "asdf";`

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong.  If it is possible to post the whole source, I'll stick it in a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Sure, thanks! Trying out a source code posting site: http://www.sourcepod.com/vzhhel20-31086 edited the header/source/main together should work all as one

Comment: much prettier: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:40b6 also this code uses `Str` s, b, and x instead of a, b, and c but all else is the same

Comment: Just found the same thing as @Dietmar_Kühl.  He was quicker than me.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `delete[]`ing the memory in you input operator, you need to make sure the `data` member is set to `0`. If you don't do that, you'll `delete[]` a non-null pointer which was already `delete[]`d in your `push_back()` and your program will have undefined behavior:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Str& s) {
    delete[] s.data;
    s.data = 0; // needed to keep your class invariants correct
    s.length = s.limit = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aahh didn't catch that! That was exactly it, this means that the `delete[]`d memory `data` pointed to was used in some other way before `push_back()` was called and  `push_back()` then deleted that memory (which would have an unknown, different purpose)?

Comment: @Instinc: no. After `delete[] s.data` the member `s.data` clearly contained a pointer to already `delete[]`d memory. Then in your `push_back()` you would allocate new memory and call `delete[] s.data` which would try to `delete[]` a pointer which is already `delete[]`ed, thereby causing undefined behavior (under the hood it probably corrupted something in the memory management system).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is not allocating space for a terminating null character (and is not storing it either).

I have a feeling, changing it to:

```
Str::Str(const char* cp) {
    limit = length = std::strlen(cp);
    data = new char[length+1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i != length; ++i)
       data[i] = cp[i];
    data[length] = '\0';
}
```

will fix your problem.

While at it I am going to suggest changing `push_back` a little so that it always adds a terminating null character.

```
void Str::push_back(char c) {
    if (length == limit) {
        limit = (limit > 0 ? limit*2 : 1);
        char* newData = new char[limit+1];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            newData[i] = data[i];

        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
    data[length++] = c;
    data[length] = '\0';
}
```

**Update**

The answer by @Dietmar is a key fix. Not sure whether that's all you need.

Comment: Even with this change it still crashes, do I need the terminating null though even when no other part of my code checks for it?

Comment: Try updating `push_back` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Copied in both functions, still the same for some reason

Comment: Adding a null terminator the string is neither necessary nor does it fix the problem.

Comment: @Instinct, the answer suggested by Dietmar should fix any remaining problems.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Your answer is a key fix. Not sure whether that solves all the problems.